# JavaFx and Spring boot without FXML

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, javafx-8

All the examples of spring and javafx implementation show the use of fxml, i would like to evade that.

[image: my project hierarchy]

```
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan({"com.test.dao","com.test.service.impl","com.test.service","com.service.guiModules"})
public class Main extends Application {

      private Workbench workbench;

      private TestModule testModule = new TestModule();

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //this commented just launches the spring app, but no gui
        SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);

        //and when i use this it launches the gui, but spring cant manage beans
    //  Application.launch(args);
    }



    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
         Scene myScene = new Scene(initWorkbench());

            primaryStage.setTitle("Simple WorkbenchFX Demo");
            primaryStage.setScene(myScene);
            primaryStage.setWidth(1000);
            primaryStage.setHeight(700);
            primaryStage.show();
            primaryStage.centerOnScreen();

    }

     private Workbench initWorkbench() {
            workbench = Workbench.builder(

                    testModule

            ).build();
            return workbench;
          }
```

then here is the GUI class

```
@Component
public class TestGui extends BorderPane {
// here would be gui and necesery gui logic, also here would i use my services impls
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

  public TestGui() {
    HBox hbox = new HBox();
    Button btn = new Button();
    Label lbl = new Label();
    hbox.getChildren().addAll(btn,lbl);
    setCenter(hbox);

    btn.setOnAction(e->lbl.setText(personService.getSomething()));
  }
```

here finally is class that returns gui to main classes workbench

```
public class TestModule extends WorkbenchModule {
        //it just serves that TestGui class to the main classes workbench
  public TestModule() {
    super("Hello World", MaterialDesignIcon.HUMAN_HANDSUP);
  }

  @Override
  public Node activate() {
    return new TestGui();
  }

}
```

I assume i must annotate TestGui class as component, so that later spring would know how to manage it.
And i wont other classes its just Dao, POJO and service and its implementation.

In my AppConfig class i would like to tell spring to scan for beans in modules package

Normally when they use spring boot they use Fxml, so when they load files using FXML loader they do something like this. Is there anyway to rework this to help me with what i need ? i dont need or on plan using fxml, so i would like to just load javaclasses
private final ResourceBundle resourceBundle;
private final ApplicationContext context;

```
@Autowired
public AppConfig(ApplicationContext context, ResourceBundle resourceBundle) {
    this.resourceBundle = resourceBundle;
    this.context = context;
}

public Parent load(String fxmlPath) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
    loader.setControllerFactory(context::getBean); //Spring now FXML Controller Factory
    loader.setResources(resourceBundle);
    loader.setLocation(getClass().getResource(fxmlPath));
    return loader.load();
}
```

aside from spring and mysql dependencies in my pom i also have [this](https://github.com/dlemmermann/WorkbenchFX) and its what i am using to just load my gui classes to main stage

I understand that what i am asking is quite broad question, but i havent found one single example of spring boot and javafx without fxml.

Answer (score 1):

Annotate your WorkbenchModule

```
@Component
public class TestModule extends WorkbenchModule {
  private Node node;

  public TestModule() {
    super("Test module", MaterialDesignIcon.DATABASE);
    TextField id = new TextField();
    Button load = new Button("Test");
    node = new FlowPane(id, load);
  }

  @Override
  public Node activate() {
    return node;
  }

}
```

1. Inject to your Application class
2. Create a Workbench bean by annotating the initWorkbench method
3. Initialize Spring in the init method
4. When creating the scene, make sure to use the Workbench bean created Spring by using springContext.getBean(Workbench.class)

*

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
public class TestApplication extends Application {
  private ConfigurableApplicationContext springContext;
  // 1
  @Autowired
  private TestModule testModule;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
  }

  // 3
  @Override
  public void init() throws Exception {
    springContext = SpringApplication.run(OssApplication.class);
  }

  @Override
  public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    // 4
    Workbench workbench = springContext.getBean(Workbench.class);
    Scene scene = new Scene(workbench);

    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.setWidth(1000);
    primaryStage.setHeight(700);
    primaryStage.show();
    primaryStage.centerOnScreen();
  }

  @Override
  public void stop() {
    springContext.close();
  }

  // 2
  @Bean
  public Workbench initWorkbench() {
    Workbench workbench = Workbench.builder(
            testModule
            )
            .build();
    return workbench;
  }
}
```